# How to circumvent paste-block with typing-script (on a Mac)

Tags: applescript, keyboard-shortcuts, clipboard, remote-desktop, typing

I need to RDC into a restricted-use system using Microsoft's Remote Desktop Connection, and I have a Mac. On the Windows system, I am not allowed to copy (reasonable, to protect confidential data) nor to paste, which is not reasonable, as I often would have some piece code from elsewhere that I would love to have on the system.

However, I am obviously allowed to type. My questions is, what is the best practice for such a situation?

My guess: Could I have an AppleScript "typing" everything on the clipboard after using a keyboard shortcut?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your question is pretty general, hopefully I understood correctly. The following can be done with Applescript.

```
tell application "System Events"
        set temp to the clipboard
        set the clipboard to "sometext"
        keystroke "v" using command down -- paste
        keystroke "some text you want to type"
end tell
```

The above shows two things : Setting the clipboard value and sending keystrokes. They would both have to be modified for your exact circumstance.

To automatically run the script on a keyboard shortcut you have two options : Use a third party utility like BetterTouchTool and assign the script to a shortcut. Otherwise create a new Automator Service that includes the script and assign it a shortcut in System Preferences.

Comment: Thanks, Kassym! In the end, a simple "tell app "System Events" to keystroke (the clipboard)" did the trick, and Automator indeed let me save it as a service (after I added a Run AppleScript to the workflow), and I could assign a keyboard shortcut for it. Brilliant. One must love the mac.